# Плагин intl-tel-input, как убрать +?

Tags: jquery, form

Я использую для маски номера плагин intl-tel-input. Я хочу убрать "+" из маски и оставить только коды стран. То есть чтоб на почту приходило только "*код страны* номер". Это возможно сделать в этом плагине?

Comment: По идее можете повесить лиснер на событие `countrychange`, получать номер при помощи `getNumber()` метода, делать ему `.replace('+', '')` и при помощи сеттера `setNumber()` задать номер без "+". Но нужно тестировать. И для использования `getNumber()`, `setNumber()` вроде как должен быть подключен [Utilities Script](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#utilities-script).